# Error Laravel : Undefined Offset:0

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps

I got an Error `undefined offset:0` when I execute the code below in Laravel Controller.

```
public function index() {
        $maps = Gmaps_Geocache::all();

        $latitude1 = -7.325374900000001;    
        $longitude1 = 108.2251681;

        $latitude2 = -7.331842799999999;        
        $longitude2 = 108.2237382;

        $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude1.",".$longitude1."&destinations=".$latitude2.",".$longitude2."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");

        $data = json_decode($dataJson,true);
        $nilaiJarak = $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];

        return view('maps', compact('maps','nilaiJarak'));
    }
```

how to solve it?

Comment: dd($data); i think this array is empty

Comment: what are u mean? i donot understand

Comment: @MuhammadAnwari Check `$data` array, as @J.Doe mentioned. Error says that there is no array element with 0 index. As arrays are numbered from 0, therefore `$data` array is empty.